# 2 column layout with sticky header and footer

Tags: html, css

I would like to create this http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_5.html
without using frames. I want to be able to set a right border on the left menu div but the left menu div doesn't extend from the header to the footer on the examples I find. Other examples use a repeating .jpg to draw the right border for the left menu div. This should be a n easy task shouldnt it? Please help...

Comment: **What have you tried?**

Answer (score 0):

You should try `CSS layout generator`. [**http://csslayoutgenerator.com/**](http://csslayoutgenerator.com/)

Comment: Sowmya this is such a cool tool. But try and create a 2 column page where the left (menu) column stretches from the header to the footer. This is what I am trying to achieve. The tool doesnt stretch the left column. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use Frames?? You can also use css Float: right/left and div's.

A sticky footer can you make also with css, its similar this:

```
CSS

.sticky_footer 
{
    width:                              760px;
    border-top:                         1px solid #BEC2C8;
    position:                           fixed;
    bottom:                             0px;
    right:                              0px;
    left:                               0px;
    padding:                            20px 0px 10px;
    background-color:                   whitesmoke;
    background-image:                   url('/img/bg_footer.png');
    background-repeat:                  repeat-x;
    background-position:                top;
}
```

page (footer)

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="sticky_footer">
        <p class="text-info" style="color: #0088cc !important; text-align: center;">
            <small> copyright ...</small>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Raymond I dont use frames at all. Can you include the html and css for the whole page?

Comment: Hey Cella, at the moment I cant do this because during my work without additional time. But if you will classify pages in different blogs with the css float elements and using in combination with html divs can you look at this link.                                                                       http://www.sitemasters.be/tutorials/5/1/90/CSS/Div_element